# PHP CSV upload checking and skipping headers line

Tags: php, mysql, csv, upload, header

```
 if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO PowerFlex (customerCode, postCode,Name, Address1,Address2) VALUES 
                ( 
 '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[3])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[4])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[5])."', 

 etc

                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"')); 
    // 
}
```

This code uploads my CSV into the database but doesn't skip the headers(fields)  in the first line of CSV and also doesn't check the headers against my database table's headers.
how do I do that ?

Comment: Apart from that you will have to update your general programming skills, so that you can come up with a little more than just _“how do i do that?”_ in cases like this – `addslashes` is the wrong function to use here. Please go read up on a) how to prevent SQL injection the _right_ way, and b) why you should not use the mysql_ functions any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like:

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    for ($lines = 0; $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'); $lines++) {
        if ($lines == 0) continue;

        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO PowerFlex (customerCode, postCode,Name, Address1,Address2) VALUES 
                ( 
 '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[3])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[4])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[5])."', 

 etc

                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } 
    // 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = fgets(...); // <= skip first line as header

$data = fgets(...); // <= read first data

//loop through the csv file and insert into database 
do { 
    if ($data[0]) { 
      ...
    } 
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'));
```

Comment: Hey bro, i'm not too good at PHP, can you explain the first two things that u mentioned? what do i do there ?

Comment: read 2 line before `do {`.


`fgets(...)` means `fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"')`

Comment: i'm sorry i'm not clear about it as u wrote the same could twice in the first two lines.. can you please re-write the code completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't distinguish the first line from the rest. It also relies on columns being in a specific order in the CSV.

Do a separate, initial `fgetcsv()` at the beginning and build a `$csv_fields` array, then use this array to map the file's fields with the table's ones, by name. There's a concern about missing columns in csv, as well as redundant ones, but I'll choose to ignore them in the code below. I'm sure you will find a more suitable way of handling these things.

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) 
  { 
  // the table fields
  $tbl_fields = array('customerCode', 'postCode,Name', 'Address1', 'Address2');
  //get the csv file 
  $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
  $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 
  // get the first line into a fields map
  $csv_fields = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"');
  // we will insert only common fields
  $tbl_fields = array_intersect($tbl_fields,$csv_fields);
  // if there's not at least one common field, don't go on
  if(count($tbl_fields)>0)
    {
    // we need the table's field names as keys (see below)
    $tbl_fields = array_flip($tbl_fields);
   // now let's go after the data
    while($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"'))
      {
      $data=array_map('addslashes',$data); // apply addslashes() to all values 
      $data=array_combine($csv_fields,$data); // csv fields assoc (key=>value)
      $data=array_intersect_key($data,$tbl_fields); // discard redundant
      $tbl_fields_str=implode("`,`",array_keys($data));
      $tbl_vals_str=implode("','",array_values($data));
      $q="INSERT INTO `PowerFlex` (`$tbl_fields_str`) VALUES ('$tbl_vals_str')";
      mysql_query($q);
      }
    }
  else
    echo "There's no data I can use!";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 
    $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"') // this for skipping first line in your file
    $data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"') //
    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO PowerFlex (customerCode, postCode,Name, Address1,Address2) VALUES 
                ( 
 '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[3])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[4])."', 
 '".addslashes($data[5])."', 

 etc

                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",",'"')); 
    // 
}
```